# How to set imageViews to single clicks rather than double

Tags: java, android

My android app includes a true/false game. 
The user should click either the true or false image one time and the next statement will appear. 
I need the user to click the image only once, but it is only allowing for double clicks.

Is there anyway to set the clicks to be single rather than double? 
I have checked that the focusable and focusable in touch attributes are null

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#B5FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".industry_standards_questions">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.38"
            android:background="#63FFFFFF">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="420dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Know your standards"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#0C40F1"
                android:textSize="40dp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.38">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/statement_TV"
                android:layout_width="420dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Statement"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#020202"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.38"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/trueImage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/true_button"></ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/falseImage"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/false_button"></ImageView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.38">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="20dp"
                >


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/finish"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="Finish"
                    android:textColor="#050505"
                    android:background="#E4DABC53"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

---

```
package com.example.securityapp;

import androidx.annotation.StringRes;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class industry_standards_questions extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference databaseUsers;
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    TextView stmnt;
    ImageView image_true, image_false;
    Button points;

    Statements tfStatements;
    int statementsLength;

    ArrayList<Item> statementList;
    int currentStatement = 0;
    int grade = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_industry_standards_questions);

        databaseUsers = database.getReference();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        stmnt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statement_TV);

        image_true = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.trueImage);
        image_false = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.falseImage);

        tfStatements = new Statements();
        statementsLength = tfStatements.tfStatements.length;

        statementList = new ArrayList<>();

        points = (Button) findViewById(R.id.final_score);

        for(int i = 0; i < statementsLength; i++){
            statementList.add(new Item(tfStatements.getStatement(i), tfStatements.getAnswer(i)));
        }

        Collections.shuffle(statementList);

        setStmnt(currentStatement);



        image_true.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkAnswer(currentStatement)) {
                    grade++;
                    if (currentStatement < statementsLength - 1)
                        setStmnt(currentStatement);
                }
                currentStatement++;
                if(currentStatement >= statementsLength) { score(); }
            }

        });

        image_false.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!checkAnswer(currentStatement)){
                    grade++;
                    if(currentStatement < statementsLength -1)
                        setStmnt(currentStatement);
                    }
                currentStatement++;
                if(currentStatement >= statementsLength) { score(); }
                }

        });

    }

    // show Statement
    private void setStmnt(int number){
        stmnt.setText(statementList.get(number).getStatement());
    }

    //check is answer is right
    private boolean checkAnswer(int number){
        String answer = statementList.get(number).getAnswer();
        return answer.equals("true");
    }

    public void score(){
        Users.currentUser.setScore(grade);
        databaseUsers.child(Users.currentUserId).setValue(Users.currentUser);
     Toast.makeText(this, "You scored " + grade + " points!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     grade = 0;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your view to not be focusable with `view.setFocusable(false)`, because if they are focusable, the first touch will "focus" them (which has no effects on ImageViews) and the second will call the onClick()-method.

If it is set to false, you will just need one click to call your onClick()-method.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply . Unfortunately the problem is still occurring. Sometimes double clicks are required and sometimes not

Comment: Did you delete the android:focusableInTouchMode="true" from the ImageView in your xml-file?

Comment: It was never in the xml file which is why I am unsure of what could be causing the issue :(

Comment: In the code you posted above, there is the focusableInTouchMode-attribute in the "falseImage"-ImageView. But that shouldn't be the problem, because you are overwriting this value in your java.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I just saw that and removed it, but the problem is still persisting and is breaking the game as only 8 clicks should be allowed but now the double clicking is causing an issue